# Perform a function on each value of a vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector, a, shape (10000,1) filled with values. I also have vector b, same shape, filled with zeros. I want to take my function, apply it to each value in vector a, return those values into vector b. Below is what I tried, as well as a few variations of this. How can I perform this function on each value of the vector and replace each zero in vector b with what that function returns?

```
for i=1:length(a)
    b(i) = function(a)
end
```

Comment: Maybe you want `b(i) = function(a(i))`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to do this

```
b = arrayfun(@someFunction, a); % Calls b(i) = someFunction(a(i)) for all elements of a
```

(Although it's common in MATLAB to try and make `someFunction` be "[vectorised](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html)", so that you can instead say simple `b = someFunction(a)`)

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. (I'll update my answer)